# Salesforce Chatter - Disabling Edit / Delete

Tags: chatter

I have a question about Salesforce Chatter. Is there a way to disable Edit or Delete for Posts and Private Messages, including the comments or likes for the posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, all users who are assigned a profile that has the feed post editing permissions enabled can edit their posts and comments. If needed, you can disable feed post editing for all users in your organization, regardless of their assigned user profile. You can also shut off post and comment editing for all users assigned the “Can Approve Feed Post and Comment” permission.

- From Setup, enter Chatter Settings in the Quick Find box, then
  select Chatter Settings.
- Click Edit.
- In the Post and Comment Modification section, deselect Allow users
  to edit posts and comments.
  [image]
- Click Save.
- If you have assigned the “Can Approve Feed Post and Comment”
  permission, disable that on the relevant permission sets.

“Can Approve Feed Post and Comment” lets assigned users edit and delete any post or comment in any Chatter feed those users have access to. This permission is available under **Setup | Permission Sets | Select a permission set | System Permissions**.

The feed post editing feature is disabled for your entire organization (or, for step 5, for all users assigned the edited permission set). Users can no longer edit posts and comments.

Read more about them here:-

1. [Feed Post and Comments Editing Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_admin_feed_post_editing.htm&type=5)
2. [Disable Edit Feed Post for All Users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_admin_feeds_edit_posts_disable.htm&type=5)

About deleting a post:-

Chatter posts, like any other data in Salesforce, are stored forever unless an authorized person deletes them. Here's who can delete posts:

- Users without any special permissions can delete their own posts,
  posts on their own Chatter wall items, and posts on records they own.
- Chatter Moderator Users can also delete posts in Chatter.
- An Administrator with the “Manage Chatter Messages” profile
  permission can view and delete all Users' messages in Chatter; for
  example, for compliance purposes.
- Users with "Modify All Data" profile permission.
- Users with the "Can Approve Feed Post and Comment" profile
  permission.

Read more here:- [Delete Chatter Posts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000175873&type=1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Sanket!