# Block edit/delete permissions to FeedItem and FeedComment

Tags: chatter, servicecloud, chatter-feed

I hope someone can help me with a solution to a problem I'm having regarding posts and comments on chatter. So, the idea is to block both the editing and deletion of post(`FeedItem`) or `FeedComment` records in cases, regardless of whether the user created the case or not. Regarding editing, I managed to find a satisfactory solution through the Chatter Settings configuration. The same cannot be said for deletion. I've checked the settings within `profiles` and `permission sets`, as well as the options mentioned in this other [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257538/salesforce-chatter-disabling-edit-delete) all without success. I appreciate your attention and help in advance."

I hope this helps, and if you have any further questions or need assistance with your Salesforce issue, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to provide a solution I found for my problem, and perhaps it can help others. Through my research, I came to the conclusion that blocking deletions of records in Chatter is not included in the standard solution provided by Salesforce. To resolve my issue, I needed to install an [app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000004cSsOEAU&tab=r) available on the AppExchange (free) and recently updated. The solution is straightforward; by simply installing it, the deletion block was automatically disabled.

Resources:

- https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdoWIUAZ/stop-the-ability-for-any-group-member-to-delete-chatter-posts-of-other-users
- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_chatter_posts_delete.htm&type=5
- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385670&type=1